# Yeoman webapp grunt build error behind proxy

Tags: web-applications, proxy, gruntjs, generator, yeoman

When running the 'grunt build' command for the Yeoman webb-app generator, it doesn't "download the svg source" for the final dist folder.

The error message says:

```
Looking for Modernizr references in dist/styles/main.css >> svg
Downloading source files
A server error occurred attempting to download a file: 
Fatal error: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Does anyone have a solution? I'm also behind a proxy if that helps.

I'm currently using: 
npm - 1.4.8,
yo - 1.1.2,
bower - 1.3.3

Comment: I have the same issue, here 11 months after, with a completely new install. Did you find out what the issue was?